# How to generate scan results for the external endpoints to pass salesforce security review?

Tags: security-review, security-scanner, chimera-security-scanner

I have build Salesforce appexchange app and i have used amazon s3 server api to store files in amazon server. I have generated the report for security and quality check but i dont know how to generate a scan result for external endpoints. Can some one guide me here?

Comment: how did you come up with the solution can you share your knowledge